# Convert number to rank - Java

Tags: java

Does anyone know of a way to convert numbers into their corresponding ranks in Java?

For example:
1 => first
2 => second
11 => eleventh
37 => thirty-seventh
etc..

Comment: This is not the place to get your homework done - at least not that way. In any case, try to do this in pseudocode first.

Comment: Isn't 1st, 5th, 154th not a solution?

Comment: i would do this for a grilled-pizza-with-extra-cheese....documentation would require an additional beer ;)

Comment: If you know `Map` data structure then you can make use of that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the code from [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) to change the numbers into words. After it you would have to something like this:

```
String numberAsWord =  EnglishNumberToWords.convert()     //The Method from the site
String numberAsRank = null;
if(numberAsWord.equals("one){
numberasRank = "first";
}else if(numberAsWord.equals("two"){
...
}else{
numberasRank = numberAsWord + "th"
}
```

Comment: Or he could just alter the source of the class `EnglishNumberToWords` to do what he needs it to do.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the **ordinal**.

I'm not aware of any libraries, but have a look at:

[How to get the ordinal suffix of a number for many languages in Java or Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071286/how-to-get-the-ordinal-suffix-of-a-number-for-many-languages-in-java-or-groovy)

or

http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16906&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks James, but unfortunately I need it to use "first","second" and not 1st, 2nd :-(

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> ranks = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
ranks.put(1, "first");
ranks.put(2, "second");
...
ranks.put(11, "eleventh");
```

Then when you need it you can ask for it by doing this:

```
int number = 1;
System.out.println("The corresponding rank for " + number + " is: " + ranks.get(number));
```

Comment: That's fine, but if I wanted to get 1000000 (millionth), I would need a map containing a million items...

Comment: Obviously there is no way to know what's the corresponding ranking number in the desired language. This is example is using english language. For more complex scenario you will need a complete list stored in a database. Or use somehow a more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: That is true of arbitrary ordinals, but there is a definite structure to the result in this case.

Comment: Yeah like you said there is a definite structure. This is a simple way to do it. Not the best one. Using an algorithm would be the correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it as Alfredo suggests. It's tedious and would only work up to some upper limit (which is when you get tired of hard-coding in values).

Otherwise you're going to have to program in a general algorithm for this. A good starting point would be reading this: http://home.comcast.net/~igpl/NWA.html

Comment: Thanks tskuzzy, that sorta links in with Artjom's answer :-)